# Tkinter Checkbutton Not Working Even After Clicked

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am writing a simple tic-tac-toe game that anyone can win. The player will have to put an X on the board, and check the "I confirm my move." check button. Once the check button is checked, the program jumps into a checking process. If the X is placed at the correct cell, a messagebox pops up saying that that won. However, if they place the X at the wrong cell, a messagebox will pop up to mock the player. The problem I am having now is that the messageboxes do not show up even after the check button is clicked on. What went wrong? Thank  you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

window=tk.Tk()
window.title('Tic-Tac-Toe')

def button1_clicked():
    button1.configure(text='X')
    return True
def button2_clicked():
    button2.configure(text='X')
    return True
def button3_clicked():
    button3.configure(text='X')
    return True
def button4_clicked():
    button4.configure(text='X')
    return True
def checked():
    if button1_clicked==True:
        messagebox.showinfo('Good job!','You just won a tic-tac-toe game that anyone can win.')
    if button2_clicked==True or button3_clicked==True or button4_clicked==True:  
        messagebox.showinfo('BRUH!','The only best move was obvious.')

t=tk.IntVar()
label1=tk.Label(window,text='X')
label2=tk.Label(window,text='O')
label3=tk.Label(window,text='O')
label4=tk.Label(window,text='X')
label5=tk.Label(window,text='O')
button1=tk.Button(window,text=' ',command=button1_clicked)
button2=tk.Button(window,text=' ',command=button2_clicked)
button3=tk.Button(window,text=' ',command=button3_clicked)
button4=tk.Button(window,text=' ',command=button4_clicked)
check=tk.Checkbutton(window,text='I confirm my move.',variable=t,command=checked)

label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
label2.grid(row=0,column=1)
label3.grid(row=0,column=2)
label4.grid(row=1,column=0)
label5.grid(row=1,column=1)
button1.grid(row=2,column=0)
button2.grid(row=2,column=2)
button3.grid(row=1,column=2)
button4.grid(row=2,column=1)
check.grid(row=3,column=1)

messagebox.showinfo('Instruction','This is a tic-tac-toe game that anyone can win.')
messagebox.showinfo('Instruction','Click on an empty cell to put X.')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code example does not follow Minimal Reproducible Example. Please edit yout code so that it does. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `True` from buttons clicks serves no purpose.

Your `checked()` function is called when checkbox is clicked. In that function you check if `button1_clicked` and `button2_clicked` are true. However you have never set those `buttonx_clicked` values. So they cannot be true (nor false).

You have to check if text in yout button is `X`, because that is the only thing you change when you click those buttons:

```
if button1['text'] == "X":
    messagebox.showinfo('Good job!','You just won a tic-tac-toe game that anyone can win.')
if button2['text'] == "X" or button3['text'] == "X" or button4['text'] == "X":
    messagebox.showinfo('BRUH!','The only best move was obvious.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Messageboxes do not show up even after the check button is clicked on, because your button1_clicked,button2_clicked,.. etc. these conditions are not true, and you should call these function in this way

```
def checked():
    if button1_clicked()==True:
        messagebox.showinfo('Good job!','You just won a tic-tac-toe game that anyone can win.')
    if button2_clicked()==True or button3_clicked()==True or button4_clicked()==True:  
        messagebox.showinfo('BRUH!','The only best move was obvious.')
```

There should be "()" after the fucntion name.

Comment: All the `buttonX_clicked()` functions return `True`, so I wonder why this answer is accepted.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I ran the program and there indeed was some problem.

Comment: The code that I gave was just example of how buttonX_clicked function to be called, well it wasn't the actual logic.